# Mysql palavras chaves reservadas

Tags: mysql, palavras-reservadas

Quando entro no php my admin ele exibe a seguinte mensagem

> The column name 'default' is a MySQL reserved keyword.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

referente a um campo chamado `default` da minha tabela

a minha pergunta é: isso pode trazer algum transtorno na hora do cadastro e utilização desse campo?

Comment: Já não está tendo problema :P ?

Comment: @rray  a mensagem apareceu apenas como aviso, não realizei nenhum insert até o momento.. é que o insert e feito por uma trigger, então quero ter certeza que não dará problemas antes de testar

Comment: Mude o nome do campo que é melhor, vc pode escapar ele com backsticks mas não acho pratico.

Comment: Não faz parte das boas práticas usar palavras reservadas, na via das dúvidas, alterar o nome da coluna vai te dar menos dor de cabeça do que um possível problema que isso possa causar no futuro.

Comment: @EdsonHoracioJunior alterei para `is_default`

Answer (score 2):

Não é uma boa prática, porém creio que o único transtorno maior que você vai ter, é ter que usar escapes, como por exemplo `"default"` ou entre os backticks -> `

Answer (score 2):

Palavras como *default*, *order*, *name*, dentre outras, são reservadas.

É permitido usar porém é preciso escapar com backsticks

```
 `default`
```