# Minha query que antes funcionava, agora não vai pro bd de jeito nenhum

Tags: php, mysql

Do nada minhas querys não são mais aceitas pelo meu BD. Isso tanto pelo site em php como direto com um INSERT no phpmyadmin. Vejam se podem me dá uma luz:

```
CREATE TABLE `despesas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `desc` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `venc` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `valor` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `recibo` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

E essa é minha query no php:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO despesas (desc, venc, valor, recibo) values('$desc', '$venc', '$val', '" . $rec . "')";
        $salva = mysqli_query(BDConexao(), $query);
```

Se eu tentar inserir direto no phpmyadmin também não vai:

```
INSERT INTO despesas (desc, venc, valor, recibo) values('AWS Amazon', '05/02/2017', '25,00', 'Chrysanthemum.jpg')
```

Aí eu pergunto à vocês, seria algo errado com meu banco de dados?

Comment: O `desc` é uma palavra reservada do MySQL, já tentou utilizar \`desc\`, entre ``.

Comment: Veja isto: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109125/mysql-palavras-chaves-reservadas

Comment: Muito Obrigado, funcionou.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Mysql palavras chaves reservadas](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/109125/mysql-palavras-chaves-reservadas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom vamos lá,

existem dois problemas na sua query:

1. **O campo id**: A sua tabela está definida para impedir registros com este campo nullo: *id int(11) **NOT NULL**,* e dentro do insert você não esta informando este campo, caso queria que este campo seja gerado automaticamente você tem que configura-lo com AUTO INCREMENT.
2. **A palavra DESC**: Como nosso amigo @Inkeliz comentou, é uma palavra reservada do MySQL, para que sua query funcione você precisará colocar esta palavra entre "`", ou, alterar o nome do campo para descricao.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Muito obrigado Roberto.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo se você definir que o campo `id` não pode ser nulo deverá informar um valor para ele como abaixo:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO despesas ('id',descricao, vencimento, valor, recibo) values(1,'$desc', '$venc', '$val', '" . $rec . "')";
        $salva = mysqli_query(BDConexao(), $query);
```

Caso queira que seja incrementado sequencialmente deve criar a tabela e a `query` desta forma:

```
CREATE TABLE `despesas` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,//<-- Veja o AUTO_INCREMENT aqui
  `descricao` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `vencimento` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `valor` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `recibo` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

$query = "INSERT INTO despesas (descricao, vencimento, valor, recibo) values('$desc', '$venc', '$val', '" . $rec . "')";
            $salva = mysqli_query(BDConexao(), $query);
```

Veja que alterei também a palavra `desc` que é uma palavra reservada do MySQL. Com isso acredito que tudo funcionará bem.

Comment: Obrigado Rogers.